# Need Min start date and Max end date for the continuous ranges in a partition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table and need the minimum start date and maximum end date if the ranges are continuous.

Table/Records:

```
Primary Key Employee Key    Start Date  End Date
23145       3245            2020-09-01  2021-01-01
23146       3245            2021-01-01  2021-01-02
            
23147       3245            2021-03-10  2021-12-15
23148       3245            2021-12-15  2022-01-06
23149       3245            2022-01-06  2047-01-01
23150       3245            2047-01-01  2199-12-31
```

Expectation

```
Employee Key    Start Date  End Date
3245            2020-09-01  2021-01-02
3245            2021-03-10  2199-12-31
```

Comment: Are you authorized to disclose the DDL for the table, or should we just assume that all columns are `NVarChar(max)`?

Comment: Search "gaps and islands"

Answer (score 0):

Create this function first:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Get_EndDate]
        (
                @EmployeeKey    int
            ,   @EndDate        date
        )
    RETURNS date
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @NewEndDate date = (
                                        SELECT  EndDate 
                                        FROM    Employee    
                                        WHERE   EmployeeKey =   @EmployeeKey
                                            AND StartDate   =   @EndDate)
        IF  @NewEndDate IS NOT NULL
            RETURN dbo.Get_EndDate(@EmployeeKey, @NewEndDate)
        ;
        SET @NewEndDate = @EndDate
        RETURN @NewEndDate
    END
GO
```

Then execute this:

```
;WITH   FinalEmployee   AS
    (
        SELECT
                EmployeeKey
            ,   StartDate
            ,   EndDate = dbo.Get_EndDate(EmployeeKey, EndDate)
        FROM    dbo.Employee
    )

SELECT  
        EmployeeKey
    ,   StartDate   =   MIN(StartDate)
    ,   EndDate
FROM    FinalEmployee
GROUP BY    EmployeeKey, EndDate
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Andy3B.  I will look into this and come back to you. Is there a way to get this without using function?

Comment: Perhaps using recursive CTEs. I found the function easier. Remember to vote if you accept the answer. thanks.

Comment: Well, no up vote. Another hit and run.

Comment: i am still checking this. Thanks for commenting.